# Why allow questions "on hold" to be edited?

Tags: discussion

[I've just had this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045253/toggle-divs-using-jquery) appear at the top of my feed because someone edited it by changing the wording a little.

You can't answer a question `[on hold]` so why allow editing? Someone is clearly editing to get ranking points (imho) but it's futile and a bit annoying that they get bumped up feeds.

Comment: The point of [on-hold] *is* to edit the question.  If editing it can't fix it then it should be deleted.

Comment: By the question poster I totally get, but by someone else? Surely a question put on hold by mods/high rep users, can't be guessed what the original post should have said by someone else ?

Comment: That post wasn't edited by someone else. It was edited by the original poster.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sh*t - apologies guys - I rest my case - although my point about being able to be edited by someone else still stands

Comment: @DarrenSweeney People only get 'ranking points' if their edit is accepted. And ideally, only useful edits are accepted - which results in a net positive for the site.

Comment: *Surely a question put on hold by mods/high rep users, can't be guessed what the original post should have said by someone else?* It could if the person editing it can tell what the problem is due to being more familiar with the language/task, having had the problem before, a chat session with the OP, is bilingual and can tell what the OP is trying to say, etc. Really, it depends on why the question was unclear in the first place.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image: If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.]

Comment: -1 Not enough freehand red circles.

Comment: I still don't get it ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° )

Answer (score 5):

The idea with "on hold" is that people, especially the original poster, can edit the question to get it reopened. Removing the ability to edit closed / on-hold questions would undermine the system.

Theoretically, the user would have made an edit that causes the post to be no longer close-worthy, the edit would bump it so that people like you see it, and you would cast a reopen vote.

Sometimes people don't get the editing part right. There's no reason to shut off editing to these *entirely* just because sometimes the theory doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Questions that are on hold *should* be edited (if at all possible) to clarify, fix spelling and grammar mistakes etc. It might be just what's needed to convert something unanswerable into something that produces a gem of an answer.

Editing puts the question into the reopen queue where it's reviewed and reopened if enough people agree that it's now on topic and answerable.

If the question isn't fixable then, yes, there's no point in editing.